# Swift isLockingFocusWithCustomLensPositionSupported always returns false

Tags: swift, avcapturedevice, avcapture, avcam

I want to set the lens distance of my iPhoneX to a constant.
In order to check if that is supported, I check the `isLockingFocusWithCustomLensPositionSupported` property of my device, as described in the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/2361529-islockingfocuswithcustomlensposi

The method always returns false, even when the device is locked for configuration, which means that calling the method `setFocusModeLocked(lensPosition, completionHandler)` will alway throw an error.
Why is this the case, and how to correctly call the `setFocusModeLocked()` ?

Below is my approach:

```
    let device = self.deviceInput.device 
    do { 
         try device.lockForConfiguration() 
         if device.isFocusPointOfInterestSupported && device.isFocusModeSupported(focusMode) 
         { 
          // this returns true 
         } 
         if device.isLockingFocusWithCustomLensPositionSupported 
         { 
           //this always returns false
           device.setFocusModeLocked(lensPosition: focusDistance, completionHandler: nil) 
         } 
         device.unlockForConfiguration() 
    } catch { 
         print("Could not lock device for configuration: \(error)")
    }
```

Tested on iPhoneX, iOS 12

Comment: You ever figure this out?

Comment: @kanso Unfortunately not, haven't checked if this appears in ios 14